# Can't send data to the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, payload

I have been trying to add the functionality of adding favourites in the movie app I created by watching a tutorial about Redux, but for some reason the state is always empty.
This is what my action and reducers look like

**Reducers**

```
const initState = {
  favourites: [],
};

const favouriteReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_FAVOURITE":
      return {
        ...state,
        favourites: action.payload.favourites,
      };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default favouriteReducer;
```

**actions**

```
 export const favouriteActions = () => {
  return {
    type: "ADD_FAVOURITE",
    payload: "zz",
  };
};
```

The action is dispatched and showed in the redux dev tools too but nothing is added to the favorite state which I have created.

I have this onclick event set to an image of the star on which I actually want to pass in the Id of the movie which **I have access** to from another state.

```
const addFav = () => {
    dispatch(favouriteActions(id));
  };
reutrn{
<img src={favNot} onClick={addFav} />
}
```

I am just posting the main part of my component file here. I have also attached an Image showing my current state after I click in the image.

[image: after clicking on the image]

[image: after clicking on the image my state]

Comment: What do you expect `action.payload.favoriates` to be? In the reducer add `console.log(action)` to see what it actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 return {
    ...state,
    favourites: action.payload.favourites,
  };
```

Just only need "action.payload" or if you want favourites like array should change reducer : `favourites : [...state.favourites,action.payload]`

Comment: yea this worked since I want an array but it looses the previous value of the id which i have stored even though its ...state

Answer (score 0):

You are using
`case "ADD_FAVOURITE":` 
in reducer but in action the type is
`type: "ADD_FAVOURITES",`

Could this be the cause?

Comment: oh sorry it was a typo on my end :( but the actual code doesn't have this anymore and the state is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const favouriteActions = () => {
  return {
    type: "ADD_FAVOURITE",
    favourites: "zz",
  };
};
```

Please check whether above works. Instead of "playload" change to "favourites"